# HiddenInput ForeignKey Django

Tags: python, django

I can't seem to figure out why its not letting me display my ForeignKey fields that I'm passing to the forms on my templates.  I researched all over but couldn't figure out an answer with explanation that works.  Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

forms.py

```
class MeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    meeting_date = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), queryset=Date.objects.all())
    person = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), queryset=Person.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = MeetingAttendance
    fields = ['meeting_date', 'person', 'attended',]
```

Models.py

```
class MeetingAttendance(models.Model):
    meeting_date = models.ForeignKey('Date', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attended = models.BooleanField()


def __str__(self):
    return "%s - %s" % (self.person, self.meeting_date)
```

Views.py

```
def date_detail(request, slug):
    people = Person.objects.all()
    detail = Date.objects.get(slug=slug)
    MeetingFormSet = formset_factory(MeetingForm, extra=len(people)-2, max_num=len(people))
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MeetingFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            formset = form.save(commit=True)
            formset.save()
            return redirect('date_detail', slug=slug)
    else:
        initial_data = [{'person': person, 'meeting_date': detail} for person in people]
        form = MeetingFormSet(initial=initial_data)
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'people': people,
        }   
        return render(request, 'date_detail.html', context)
```

Template

```
<div class="directory panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Meeting Details</h3>
    </div><!-- end paneil-heading -->

    <div class="panel-body">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```